# Can GRUB access an NVMe drive when the BIOS lacks support for it?

Tags: bios, grub, grub2, nvme

An NVMe drive can be installed in a computer whose BIOS doesn't have support for it; any running OS can still access it using drivers, it just cannot be used as a boot drive. Does GRUB have the facilities for accessing an NVMe drive without BIOS support?

Comment: As long as Grub is on an ESP residing on a drive that is bootable it should work. That said, if the NVMe drive is in some sort of adapter that may (and likely will) require initialization and because of that not being available when needed (only later after some OS loads) then it won't work. Why don't you try instead of asking about hardware other don't and can't know?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but in the case of UEFI, it is possible to sideload a DXE driver that is compatible from a non-NVMe drive first (with EDK2 shell or Clover whatsoever), then your "(transiently) patched" UEFI firmware can load grub from an ESP on an NVMe drive.

Comment: @TomYan I think the question implies that GRUB is installed on a non-NVMe drive

Comment: @gronostaj Hmm, maybe, but same difference. I mean, whether grub can access an NVMe drive depends on your UEFI firmware as well, so either way the best you can do is to "add the support" by some means *to the firmware*.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Why is UEFI relevant?

Comment: @gronostaj That is correct.

Comment: @Melab The firmware and the installation mode is always relevant. But in this case BIOS or UEFI mode can achieve the same results. The main issue to account for is having the bootloader where the firmware CAN boot from, that's all, the drive where the system partition resides isn't that relevant and doesn't need to be in a "bootable" drive. The bootloader in BIOS would reside in a bootable's drive MBR, that being the only difference.

Comment: `having the bootloader where the firmware CAN boot from` and having files (kernel, initramfs) where the bootloader can read. `Why is UEFI relevant` AFAIK grub doesn't specifically implement drivers for specific interface / protocol in the case of UEFI, instead it implement support for something like a generic abstraction of "EFI disks", and the abstraction is created by UEFI supporting their underlying "backends" (ATA, USB, NVMe...), and UEFI to a certain degree allows you to "sideload" additional support ("DXE drivers") before you have it executing grub.

Comment: I do not think UEFI is relevant here at all. Never once did OP mention they are using UEFI. Instead, BIOS is mentioned multiple times.

Comment: Maybe, it's unfortunate many people and even vendor simply call it UEFI BIOS or BIOS, so I personally wouldn't hestiate to bring it up just in case. (IMHO there's no way for one to tell whether another is actually talking about BIOS until they use wordings like "legacy" explicitly.)

Comment: It looks like there are some patches/drivers for grub4dos that can do this https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dosahcipatch/files/ Did not try them myself to confirm, so only a comment for now.

Comment: Looking through the usage instructions for the NVMe one, `nvme --set-drive=0x80 --set-controller=0 --showselected` strongly suggests this adds a real/bios/int13H mode driver.

Answer (score 2):

This is theoretically feasible. In fact GRUB2 contains [various drivers](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/grub-core/disk) for accessing block storage already, including AHCI, SCSI and whatnot. *However, there is no NVMe driver.* (And there likely never will be.) These drivers are used to access storage locations to load kernel images and other files.

As ChanganAuto mentions in his comment, GRUB (including the initial GRUB configuration and at least the necessary GRUB modules) must reside on a drive that the BIOS can access. This could also be a USB drive.

Once GRUB has loaded the kernel (and any other required files) into memory, it passes control to the kernel. If the kernel has NVMe drivers, it can then also access the NVMe drive.

A better solution with Linux is to just have the kernel where GRUB resides, as you usually would. This may also be a feasible solution for BSD/UNIX.

If you want to chainload something (like DOS, Windows, …), things get a lot harder: You have to hook INT13 to handle disk access in real mode, then hopefully whatever you’re booting can take over using a native driver. I’m not sure whether such functionality would mesh well with GRUB’s architecture.

Comment: If one needs a separate non-NVMe drive for the EFI system partition (or BIOS GRUB partition) anyway then also having `/boot` on it is an option. I wouldn't use a flash drive for that though, they're way to unreliable.

Comment: I'm not so sure that the drivers there will work if a BIOS doesn't support / enumerate a particular (type) of block devices / interface...

Comment: @TomYan Check the AHCI driver. It directly interacts with the PCI device. So yes, this absolutely is possible and even relatively easy with GRUB2’s architecture and existing code.

Comment: What's this about INT 0x13 and chainloading Windows?

Comment: @DanielB you are right, as in, I thought these drivers play a role in the "usual" case, but apparently the truth is grub can work in different "modes": https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/tree/util/grub-install.c?h=grub-2.06#n905 (It seems that there were certain attempts to make these "native" drivers work in UEFI booting as well, but however it went, officially speaking they can only be optionally enabled for BIOS/legacy booting.)

Comment: @Melab It’s how BIOS provides Real Mode disk access. I find [the explanation on SYSLINUX’ MEMDISK module](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=MEMDISK#INT_13h_access) succinct.

Comment: Wait. Why is it unlikely that there will ever be an NVMe driver?

Comment: @Melab Because someone would have to write it and the audience (older PCs that do not support NVMe) is getting smaller every day.

Answer (score 1):

FWTW, I haven't (yet) tested this myself, but it turns out [there's](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dosahcipatch/files/) a somewhat dated [2018] patch for grub4dos 0.4.5 (not grub though) that adds AHCI and NVMe support as an int13H (bios mode) driver. The driver appears to be original work by Kai Schtrom. (It turns out he [also wrote](https://msfn.org/board/topic/178182-xp-pro-x64-os-boot-nvme/) a NVMe driver for Windows Server 2003.) Based on a comment in the source code of the grub4dos driver [around line 5000], it's based on or inspired by the OFA (Open Fabrics Alliance) NVMe driver.

---

Update: I've actually tried it now, but it didn't work for me. The AHCI part worked ok (for SATA drives, of course), but the NVMe part not at all. For the latter, all I got back was

```
Error: Can't read LBA 0 in NVMe mode!
```

The grub4dos interface to the driver is also a bit wonky (besides poorly explained): even in working AHCI mode, e.g. it complains if you don't pass a port number even if you pass `--showall` etc.

The only discussion of this I found anywhere else is on http://reboot.pro/index.php?showtopic=21872 which is a bit trollery, but mostly reports of it not working, although a few reported it working.

FWTW, there's one line there from the author that suggests this isn't a general purpose NVMe driver (even in the context of grub4dos):

> The drive number should always match the real BIOS drive number for the system, otherwise the system may hang.

So, if you don't already have a BIOS that maps NVMe drives (there are a handful [of those](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/nvme-boot-drives-with-legacy-bioses-without-uefi-using-loader-8.73861/#post-451193) like the Gigabyte MX-31), this might be useless by design.

Update2: I've looked through the source code and my (Kinston NV2) device is actually getting initialized... a bit. I say this because there are a bunch of other messages that the driver would print if it failed earlier namely:

```
    // do this for all found controllers
    for(i = 0; i < *foundControllers; i++)
    {
        // find adapter
        if(NVMeFindAdapter(&(*DevExt)[i]) != SP_RETURN_FOUND)
        {
            printf("NVMeInit Error: Can't find NVMe adapter!\n");
            return 3;
        }
        
        // initialize adapter
        if(NVMeInitialize(&(*DevExt)[i]) != TRUE)
        {
            printf("NVMeInit Error: Can't initialize NVMe adapter!\n");
            return 4;
        }

        // NVMe read initialization
        if(NVMeReadInit(&(*DevExt)[i]) != 0)
        {
            printf("NVMeInit Error: Can't initialize NVMe read!\n");
            return 5;
        }
    }

    return 0;
```

But I don't any of *those*. The one I get (about LBA 0) comes later in the code (call sequence), but the driver is badly coded and prints zero info about the device (even if it could read it from the PCIe bus) unless it can *also* read LBA 0, which it doesn't strictly need to print info about the device.

```
    // check if at least one NVMe controller is present
    if(nvmeg.FoundControllers == 0)
    {
        grub_printf("Error: No NVMe controller present!\n");
        rc = 0;
        goto cleanup;
    }

    ...........

    // read LBA 0
    // test if we can read from the specified NVMe controller
    unsigned char buf[512];
    if(NVMeRead(&nvmeg.DevExt[nvmeg.SelectedController],0,(DWORD)buf,1) != 0)
    {
        printf("Error: Can't read LBA 0 in NVMe mode!\n");
        rc = 0;
        goto cleanup;
    }
```

Also, the lifted OFA code is apparently compiled with `NVME_DEBUG` off, so I don't get any of the more detailed tracing. I'd have to recompile with that flag on for some decent diagnostics as to why it's failing.

TLDR: this might [actually] work for some devices. The developer apparently had a Samsung one.

Comment: One issue that I can think of is that the NV2 is DRAM-less, so needs to have a HMB (host memory buffer) set up, while the Samsung 970 PRO used by Kai doesn't need that. As discussed [here](https://www.pcworld.com/article/784380/host-memory-buffer-hmb-the-dram-less-nvme-technology-thats-making-ssds-cheaper.html) for instance, some game consoles (like the PlayStation 5) lack HMB support. Possibly this grub4dos driver has the same issue.

Comment: However, according to that piece, the drive should still work even sans HMB setup, albeit more slowly.

Answer (score 0):

The post
[Using GRUB to bootstrap Windows10 from a PCIe NVMe SSD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/684625/using-grub-to-bootstrap-windows10-from-a-pcie-nvme-ssd)
describes a method for booting from NVME by using a USB disk and
another bootloader.

This is the accepted answer, which also received a large bounty.

> As far as I know, there is currently no way to boot Windows from a
> PCIe device on a motherboard that doesn't natively support it using
> GRUB. That's how I ended up here.
>
> However, you can do it using [Clover EFI
> bootloader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloverefiboot/), which
> was made for booting Windows on Macs.
>
> The idea is to boot to Clover on USB, which will load a driver that
> allows you to boot Windows from you PCIe NVMe SSD.
>
> [here's](https://www.aioboot.com/en/clover-bootloader-windows/) a
> guide for installing Clover on USB.
>
> Once you have it installed, you'll need to move `NvmExpressDxe.efi`
> from `EFI/CLOVER/drivers/off` to `EFI/CLOVER/drivers/BIOS` and
> `EFI/CLOVER/drivers/UEFI`.
>
> From there, it should be as simple as booting to the USB.